# disable form submit button until user checks recaptcha checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, formik

I'm trying to disable my form's submit button until the user clicks the Google Recaptcha checkbox 'I am not a robot'

Is there anyway to do this or do I need to download a React component specific to Google Recaptcha?

Here is my simple component that contains the Google Recaptcha:

```
const RecaptchaComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Add reCaptcha
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div
            className="g-recaptcha"
            data-sitekey="6LeS8_IdfdfLtQzwUgNV4545454lhvglswww14U"
        ></div>
    )
};
```

And here is my form's onSubmit code:

```
const GameForm = () => (

<div className="app">

    <Formik
        initialValues={{
            email: "",
            name: "",
            title: ""

        }}

        onSubmit={(values) => {
            //new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
            axios({
                method: "POST",
                url: "api/gameform",
                data: JSON.stringify(values),
            });
        }}
    >

        {props => {
            const {
                values,
                isSubmitting,
                handleSubmit,

            } = props;

            return (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                    <div>Your Game</div>

                    <label htmlFor="title">
                        Game Title:
                    </label>
                    <Field
                        id="title"
                        type="text"
                        values={values.title}
                    />

                    <label htmlFor="name">
                        Name:
                    </label>
                    <Field
                        id="name"
                        type="text"
                        value={values.name}
                    />

                    <label htmlFor="email">
                        Email:
                    </label>
                    <Field
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        value={values.email}
                    />

                    <div>
                    <ReCAPTCHA 
                        sitekey="6LeS8_IUAAAAAhteegfgwwewqe223" 
                        onChange={useCallback(() => setDisableSubmit(false))}
 />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Button type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            );
        }}
    </Formik>

</div>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the [react component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha), but it's easier.

```
export const MyForm = () => {

   const [disableSubmit,setDisableSubmit] = useState(true);

   return (
     ... rest of your form
     <ReCAPTCHA 
         sitekey="6LeS8_IdfdfLtQzwUgNV4545454lhvglswww14U" 
         onChange={useCallback(() => setDisableSubmit(false))}
     />
     <button type="submit" disabled={disableSubmit}>Submit</button>
   )

}
```

EDIT:

One of my biggest pet peeves is seeing React tutorials where authors encourage devs to use functions that return JSX instead of just using functional components.

Formik's "children as a function" pattern is gross (react-router-dom does the same thing) - it should be a component:

```
const GameForm = () => {
  return <Formik ...your props>{props => <YourForm {...props}/>}</Formik>
}

const YourForm = (props) => {
   const [disableSubmit,setDisableSubmit] = useState(true);


   ... everything inside the child function in `GameForm`
}
```

Comment: thanks a few questions.  Is this code for the react component you linked to? So basically, this just sets the state of disableSubmit if the user doesn't click the 'I am not a robot' checkbox?   thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's for that component. It's certainly not necessary to use that component like I said, but it makes everything easier and more react like. `onChange` gets called when the user successfully completes the ReCAPTCHA, so as soon as they do, update the disabled state to false.

Comment: Thanks, so I tried this but get this message: React Hook "useCallback" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component. Could it be because my form is returned like this?             {props => {
                const {
     // all my consts...
                } = props;

                return (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell post all of your code. You're probably using a "helper function" [anti-pattern](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/578).

Comment: thanks, Ok I added my form...I shortened it though because it has like 75 fields.  thanks!

Comment: Just get rid of the `useCallback` and everything will continue to work fine. what's happening is your using it inside Formik's "children as a function" which is not a component, it's a callback, although you could easily turn it into a component (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks! I see the edit but if I wanted to keep it as is, where would I put the useState line?  It doesn't seem to like that either

Comment: Put the useState line at the top of the GameForm component, but I strongly encourage you not to keep it that way

Comment: thanks, so I did that...you can see the edit I made to the code.  For some reason, it doesn't like 'const' and gives me a parsing error?

Comment: You aren't using `curly braces` - you are just returning straight JSX without a return statement. The problem has been solved, "now I've got a parsing error" should really be left up to you.

Comment: Oh I see, so if I switch it to returning a component, as you mentioned, then it would work.  Thanks!